# Is it possible to nest a Spring Boot application inside another Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot RESTful microservice that a customer would like to nest inside their Spring Boot application.

Could someone tell me whether this is possible?

I was hoping this would be as simple as adding a dependency on my application in the customers maven pom file and then excluding the tomcat dependency since the customer already uses the embedded tomcat.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since they already use Spring Boot to start their app, you can simply mark all Spring Boot dependencies as `provided` in your Maven POM, this would exclude it from the JAR as well as embedded Tomcat and all related dependencies. Also make sure you don't build your JAR as a Spring Boot executable (should be the default if you're not using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`).

On the customer side, they would need to include your JAR as a dependency, and possibly add a `scanBasePackages` property to their `@SpringBootApplication`, to auto-discover your application classes, if they don't reside in a package under the one that `@springBootApplication` is on. Also, they'll need to be mindful of any URI collisions between your app and theirs, as the two will be sharing the same environment.